# Is it possible to get rid of the delete warning sound in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, warnings

When I'm dumping data from a failed macro the last thing I want is the stupid system to bleep at me. 
I looked in all the options and couldn't find one.
I tried selecting and then unselecting Options>Ease of Access>Feedback Options>Provide feedback with sound (It was already unticked so I ticked and unticked it.
I tried running an On Open event with application warnings equal to false.
None of these things work.  If a process stops and displays a warning message you need to click it doesn't need a sound to accompany it.
I know I could switch the sound off but what if I want to listen to music or a podcast?
it's extremely irritating and I'm dumbfounded that it's easier to jump out of a window than disable a totally un-necessary source of irritation.

Comment: You should fix your macros so they never fail.

Comment: This might be something you can change in Windows sound settings (If memory serves me the sound is named "asterisk" - I think you can make your own sound scheme to pick and choose what sounds are played when - but I have not done this before nor do I know exactly what level of choice you have (as in can you dictate at an application level etc.) - As far as I know Excel as an application doesn't have any settings to turn on or off system sounds.

Comment: Thanks for your advice here! - The event that triggered Asterisk was called "System Notification".  I found it through Windows Settings>Sound Control Panel>Sounds(tab)>System Notification.  
I was able to set the sound to "None" the option at the top of the column.  I thought there might be a way to set whether this was triggered or not whilst I was in Excel VBA GUI but was mistaken,

Answer (score 2):

So you've tagged this question `Excel` and `VBA`, but **Options > Ease of Access > Feedback Options > Provide feedback with sound** does not exist in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE). Not sure where you're getting that from.

Anyway, the easiest way to achieve this is hitting `Alt+F11` and then going to **Tools > Options** in the in the VBE and then unticking "Auto Syntax Check".

Faulty code will still be marked in red (or whatever color you've chosen on the Editor Format tab), but the pop-up error message will not be shown and the annoying system beep will no longer be played.

It should be noted that this will NOT prevent run-time error beeps, only syntax error beeps during coding in the VBE. I suppose you could write a Windows API call to the `winmm.dll` file which plays system sounds, if you also want to get rid of the system sound accompanying run-time errors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'd already unticked that box and it's definitely good advice in general.  I was mistaken about the source of my annoying sound - although it was triggered within Excel it was not controllable from in there - it was indeed accessible through sound settings with a system notification event.